# Cant get new_title action

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

im trying to get the new_title chat action
I just want to delete the message
I tryed with this code but its not reciving the new_title action.
Its not printing anything when new_title happen in already joined channel but when pining sth in same channel it prints the event with True new_pin and NONE new_title

Whats is the problem ?

Code :

```
@bot.on(events.ChatAction)
async def handler(event):
    print("\n--\n",event,"\n--\n")
    if event.new_title:
        print("ok")
```

Answer (score 1):

Bots cant get new_title from brodcast channels , only userbots can